# Android application launch from a widget

Tags: android, android-widget

Below is a code to launch an application from a widget...
It's not working, any suggestions?
Thank You

```
package com.acd.widget;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AcdWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
   String packageName = "air.kwd.acdsummit";
   String className = "com.package.MainActivity";
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, className));
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Grrrr.   The "it's not working" epidemic is spreading fast.  What does "it's not working" mean?  It launches the wrong app?  It crashes?  Your phone catches fire?

Comment: It's gives error in Eclipe itself :( Last 2 lines have error! I'm new to Android Dev, so I couldn't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry for grrriing.  Rajesh is correct. Look for a working example of a widget launcher on Google.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the statements in some event listener (like OnClick). You are invoking them  outside a method, where declarations (of fields, methods) are expected.

Read the [App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider) developer guide for more information on how you can achieve what you need.